# How to get the dynamically cloned table textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All,

I have table which I am cloning on clicking on button and after cloning table I need to do few calculation in the cloned table as well as in parent table. My problem is  that I am not able to do calculation on each appended(clone) table. I mean I wrote a on  blur function to do calculation with textbox value but when I am cloning table since class name is same for all textbox, in parent and cloned table my result showing in all textbox instead of corresponding part of the table. Here is my table and my jquery code which I am following.

```
 <html>
  <body>
   <table>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>
<table width="95%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" style="margin-left:10px;"  id="product">
    <thead><tr>
          <td class="mandatory"> * Product Name </td>
          <td class="label">   Qty.in Stock</td>
          <td class="mandatory">* Qty </td>
          <td class="mandatory">* Unit Price</td>
          <td class="mandatory">* List Price</td>
          <td class="mandatory">*  Total</td>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="product_details" id="tbody_product">
    <tr class="tr_product_details">
    <td> 
          <input type="text" name="txtproductName[]"  id="product-name" />
          <a href=""> 
          <img width="17" height="16" src="images/Products_small.gif"> </a>
          <input type="hidden" name="productid[]"  id="productid" />

    </td>
    <td> 
        <input type="text" name="txtqtyStock[]" id="productstock" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtQty" id="product-quatity" class="product-qty" value="3" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtUnitPrice[]" id="product-price" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txtListPrice[]" id="product-list-price" class="product-list-price" 
         />
    </td>
    <td><div style="margin-left:120px;">
        <input type="text" name="txtTotal[]" size="10" class="total-price" />
        </div>
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5"> <a href="javascript:;" class="anchor-blue product-description" id="product-description"><img width="17" height="16" src="images/spacer.gif">Product Description </a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><textarea style="width:65%" maxlength="250" rows="3" cols="30" name="txtProductDescription[]" id="textarea-product-description"></textarea> 
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" class="tbl">
        <table >
        <tr>
            <td><a href="javascript:;" class="anchor-blue discount">Discount: </a></td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="txtProductDiscount[]" size="10" class="product-discount"  /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label">Total After Discount: </td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="txtAfterDiscount[]" size="10" class="total-after-discount" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <a href="javascript:;" class="anchor-blue tax">Tax: </a></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtProductTax[]" size="10"  /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="label"> Net Total: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="txtNetTotal[]" size="10" class="net-total" /> </td>

        </tr>


      </table>

      </td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
     </table>
   <table align="left" style="margin-left:20px;">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" id="btnaddProduct" value="Add Product" class="button"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And my script which I am using :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

              var parent_qty_id = $("#product tbody:first").attr('id'); 
                var qty_attr = parent_qty_id+" tr:first .product-qty";

                $("#"+qty_attr+" .product-qty").bind("blur change",function(){  
                var product_qty = $(this).val(), product_list_price = $('#product tr td .product-list-price').val(),total;
                 total = product_qty *  product_list_price;
                // alert( $(this).children().children().attr("class"));
                 // $(this).children().children().attr("class");
                  var val = $(this).children();
                  $(val).val(total+'.00');
  });


                    $("#btnaddProduct").click(function() {
                    var count = ($("tbody .product_details").length) + 1;
                    var tblid =  $("#product tbody:first").attr('id');
                    var newid = tblid+"_"+count;
                    $('#product tbody:first').clone(true).insertAfter('#product > tbody:last').attr("id",newid);

                    $('table#product > tbody:last > tr:first input').val(' ');
                    $('table#product > tbody:last > tr:last input').val(' ');
                    $(":text.product-qty").last().val(); 
                    return false;
                    });


                 });

</script>
```

Comment: where is that button in markup??

Comment: Please set up a fiddle for this.

Comment: I have added the add button below of the html.

Comment: Hi ! Vins This is my http://jsfiddle.net/sanjoy/fzCFL/ jsfiddle link

Comment: I made an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzCFL/1/) that atleast the row addition works in.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#"+qty_attr+" .product-qty")
```

Comes out empty (no element selected) because you already added `.product-qty` in `parent_qty_id` to `qty_attr`.

```js
$("#"+qty_attr)
```

Works.

There were alot of other errors in your code which made the blur/change routine run twice etc. I've sanitized it some into this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parent_qty_id = $("#product tbody:first").attr('id'); 
    var qty_attr = parent_qty_id+" tr:first .product-qty";

    $("#"+qty_attr).blur(function(){  
        var product_qty = $(this).val(), product_list_price = $('#product tr td .product-list-price').val(),total;
        total = product_qty *  product_list_price;
        var val = $(this).children();
        $(val).val(total+'.00');
    });

    $("#btnaddProduct").click(function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        var count = ($("tbody .product_details").length) + 1;
        var tblid =  $("#product tbody:first").attr('id');
        var newid = tblid+"_"+count;
        $('#product tbody:first').clone(true).insertAfter('#product > tbody:last').attr("id",newid);

        $('table#product > tbody:last > tr:first input').val(' ');
        $('table#product > tbody:last > tr:last input').val(' ');
        $(":text.product-qty").last().val(); 
    });

});
```

Further tweaking is probably needed.